# Can I await something if there's no GetAwaiter method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, system.reactive

I saw some articles about designing a custom awaitable type:

http://books.google.com.br/books?id=1On1glEbTfIC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=create+a+custom+awaitable+type

Now consider the example below:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnA"
        Width="75"
        Margin="171,128,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Click="BtnA_Click"
        Content="Button A" />
<Button x:Name="BtnB"
        Width="75"
        Margin="273,128,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Content="Button B"  Click="BtnB_OnClick" />
```

and:

```
private async void BtnA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Awaiting Button B..");

    var sx = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventHandler, 
                                  MouseButtonEventArgs>(a => (b, c) => a(c),
                                  add => BtnB.PreviewMouseDown += add,
                                  rem => BtnB.PreviewMouseDown -= rem)
       .Do(a => a.Handled = true)
       .Take(1);

    await sx;

    MessageBox.Show("Button B Pressed after Button A");
}

private void BtnB_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button B Pressed Without Click in Button A");
}
```

Why can I `await IObservable<T>` (in this case when subscription is completed), if there's no `GetAwaiter()` method?

Is it implemented by the compiler? Is it possible to implement something that can `await` without to explicit this method (some scenarios which interfaces is being used)?
And why isn't there something like:

```
public interface ITask<out T>
{
    IAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter();
}

public interface IAwaiter<out T> : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
{
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
    T GetResult();
}
```

... or real interfaces to create a custom awaitable?

Comment: If you're reading a book on the subject what does it say on the matter?  Does it not explain its own example?

Comment: Forget it, I missed the part of "That GetAwait method can be an extension method.."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### First of all, **no**.

You can't `await` *something* that doesn't have a `GetAwaiter` method that returns *something* that has `GetResult`, `OnCompleted`, `IsCompleted` and implements `INotifyCompletion`.

### So, how are you able to `await` an `IObservable<T>`?

The compiler, on top of instance methods, also accepts `GetAwaiter` extensions methods. In this case Reactive Extensions's `Observable` provides that extension:

```
public static AsyncSubject<TSource> GetAwaiter<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source);
```

For example, this is how we can make strings awaitable (which compiles but obviously won't actually work):

```
public static Awaiter GetAwaiter(this string s)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
public abstract class Awaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    public abstract bool IsCompleted { get; }
    public abstract void GetResult();
    public abstract void OnCompleted(Action continuation);
}
```

```
await "bar";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can supply your own implementation of GetAwaiter via an extension method if one does not exist.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx