# How is Task.Delay awaitable if it's not marked async?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, ilspy

I'm looking at `Task.Delay(int)` decompiled in ILSpy:

```
// System.Threading.Tasks.Task
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)
{
    return Task.Delay(millisecondsDelay, default(CancellationToken));
}
```

This method is used like `await Task.Delay(5000);`, and the intellisense even says "(awaitable)":

[image]

So how is it that `Task.Delay(int)` isn't marked `async` (`public static async Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)`)?

Comment: It's tasks which are awaitable, not the functions that return them.

Comment: [Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx): "An “awaitable” is any type that exposes a GetAwaiter method which returns a valid “awaiter”. This GetAwaiter method may be an instance method (as it is in the case of Task and Task<TResult>), or it may be an extension method."

Comment: @I3arnon -- You edited to add c# tag, but this isn't specifically a c# question (that's just the language that ILSpy shows).  I could use `Task.Delay` from VB.NET.

Comment: @roryap it isn't, but C# (and .Net) are an umbrella tag regarding the entire MS stack. It also tells the formatter to how to format the code without hints. And to be technical, the question isn't necessarily about the TPL (since everything can be awaited) or .Net (since you can use await outside of it, e.g. WinRT).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What's awaitable is the `Task` `Task.Delay` returns. Each method returning a `Task`/`Task<TResult>` is awaitable. `async` is just an implementation detail allowing you to use `await` in that method and the whole state machine it generates.

More generally, every *thing* that has a `GetAwaiter` method ([extension methods count as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26046988/885318)) that return *something* that has `IsCompleted`, `OnCompleted` and `GetResult` can be awaited.

For example, `Task.Yield` returns `YieldAwaitable` which isn't a `Task` and looks like this:

```
public struct YieldAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion, INotifyCompletion
{
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation);
    public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation);
    public void GetResult();
    public bool IsCompleted { get; }
}
```

*`UnsafeOnCompleted` here is just an optimization, `await` would work without it.

It's important to note that the compiler in this case (same as in other cases like `GetEnumerator` for `foreach`) doesn't expect an interface or a base class. It basically uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) (i.e. *"if it walks like a duck..."*) and simply looks for a `GetAwaiter` method that returns anything (doesn't matter what type or interface or if it's a class or a struct) that has the other 3 members (`IsCompleted`, `OnCompleted` and `GetResult`)

For example, this is how you can make `await "bar"` compile (it will fail in runtime of course):

```
public static Awaiter GetAwaiter(this string s)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
public abstract class Awaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    public abstract bool IsCompleted { get; }
    public abstract void GetResult();
    public abstract void OnCompleted(Action continuation);
}
```

In conclusion, you don't need `async` to return an awaitable and moreover **most `Task`-returning methods in the .Net framework don't use it and explicitly return a `Task`**.

Comment: Nice.  So, without looking in to it yet -- is there an interface that Task or anything else implements that has a `GetAwaiter` method and has `IsCompleted`, `OnCompleted`, and `GetResult`?  In other words, how is that achieved?

Comment: Shouldn't the awaitable implement `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`?

Comment: @roryap - Look into `INotifyCompletion`

Comment: @roryap in general, no. `Task` has `GetAwaiter` without an interface. The awaiter itself (e.g. `TaskAwaiter`) implements `INotifyCompletion` (and sometimes `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`) but it doesn't need to. I'll add that to the answer.